# How to retrieve image from SD card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have this code to retrieve an image from the SD card. But it's not showing any picture in `ImageView`. I am sure the image is there on the SD card.

```
File f = new File("/mint/sdcard/e.jpg");

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
Toast.makeText(this, bitmap + "", 3).show();
bmImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: its not `mint` its `mnt`

Comment: after writing still its not working...

Comment: Do you get any error messages at logcat?

Comment: Yap its mnt thanks...its working now ...

Comment: You should probably accept @vini's answer below, as he was first on the ball. :)

Answer (score 1):

Its not `mint` its `mnt`. Make your line as,

```
File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/e.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Bitmap readImageFromExternalMemory(String name) throws IOException
{
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/"+name, userId + ".jpg");
    FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(file);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream);
    inStream.close();

    return bitmap;
}
```

You don't have to use `"/mnt/sdcard/e.jpg"`. You have to use this method:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
```

because it will return with the correct path of the external directory. Manufacturers can rename this to something else, so you have to use the method above.

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this,

```
File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/e.jpg");   
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
bmImage .setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: mention to the OP what the change is that was made (though you commented above)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to use this:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

File f = new File(sdcard+"/e.jpg");
```

Now it works on all Android phones